# Delete or move to trash email in gmail after deleted in sup

Tags: offlineimap

I have it setup to properly sync things like read status back to the server, but delete does nothing. There is some explanation of this here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/supmua/cG4L6r7MQME

But I haven't found a more concrete example. Since sup is not able to edit folders or labels on the server (i think) this may be something that offlineimap would have to handle?